# Find the value of inner HTML of a div that has more than one element in it

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking for a way to extract the value of "0.00" from this div:

[image]

I tried using this method, but it gives me an output of "NaN"

```
var c = +(document.getElementById("header-balance").innerHTML)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent), it *represents the text content of a `node`*

```
var c = +(document.getElementById("header-balance").textContent)
```

**Note from [`MDN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#Differences_from_innerHTML)**: `innerHTML` returns the HTML as its name indicates. Quite often, in order to retrieve or write text within an element, people use `innerHTML`. `textContent` should be used instead. Because the text is not parsed as HTML, it's likely to have better performance.

Comment: Works great and I learned something new, thanks, I'll give it the "tick" in 10 min

Comment: @Recuvan, I'm glad it helped! _Happy Coding_